# 403 Forbidden nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) for Django 3.1, facing issue in media files and admin css

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04

I have django 3.1 installed on digitalocean ubuntu 20.04 and nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) and using rest api

Following are my static and media files settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_in_env'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Following is my Digital Ocean Nginx Conf

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/username/backend/src;
}

location /media {
    root /home/username/backend/src;
}
```

it's giving me forbidden on even files less than 100kb.

Also After checking Nginx logs I found that Permission Denied Error.

Comment: `/home/username` does nginx have access to this **user home** folder?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by:

First:- `chmod -R 777 media` (outside of media folder)

Second:- in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project.conf`

```
location /static/ {

    root /home/username/project;
}
location /media/ {

    root /home/username/project;

}
```

to

```
location /static/ {

    alias /home/username/project/static/;
}
location /media/ {

    alias /home/username/project/media/;
}
```

Third:- reload your service file and nginx

sudo systemd restart project.service

sudo systemd restart nginx

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: the thing is my django app setting variable for STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'). and in my nginx configutation file i used this ```location \static\ { alias /home/username/project/staticfiles/;.  is this the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

Make DIR and Change permissions on Ubuntu server:

```
sudo mkdir -pv /var/www/your_project/media/
sudo chown -cR ubuntu:ubuntu /var/www/your_project/media
```

and then change settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/var/www/your_project/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/your_project/media'
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Basically, giving permission to the parent directory works.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Harsh Sonawane try put slash after media like this

```
location /media/ {
    root /home/username/backend/src;
}
```

Comment: doesnt affect anything

Answer (score 0):

Your config seems to be OK.
What you should check is you have **installed NGINX as a** **root user** or the user that has access to the files you are trying to serve.

Comment: How can this check be carried out

Answer (score -2):

Please try:

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/username/backend/src/static/;
}
location /media/ {
    root /home/username/backend/src/media/;
}
```

if that does not work try changing "root" for "alias" like this:

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/username/backend/src/static/;
}
location /media/ {
    alias /home/username/backend/src/media/;
}
```

Comment: The root directive means the root directory - alias and root can't both have the same path. It wouldnt be of any use. root directive for BOTH media and static shoukd have been written ending in /src/